# Difference between create data and create object

Tags: abap

When do we use Create Data and when do we use Create Object?

Comment: You need much more context to this question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Data : The CREATE DATA statement creates an anonymous data object and assigns the reference to the data object of the dref reference variables.By default, the data object is created in the internal session of the current program and remains there for as long as it is required. If it is no longer referenced by reference variables, it is deleted by the garbage collector. The data object can be created as a shared object using the addition area_handle.

Create Object : The CREATE OBJECT statement generates an instance of a class or object and assigns the object reference to the oref reference variables. The instance constructor of the class is called directly after the object is created.